# Forward-delete with Logitech K380 keyboard on macOS

Tags: keyboard, mouse, macos

I am using a [Logitech K380](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/keyboards/k380-multi-device.920-009599.html) keyboard with my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) running macOS Big Sur 11.6.

When I hold down the Function (`fn`) key while pressing the `delete` key on the built-in keyboard of the MacBook Pro, I get [forward-delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_key) action. That is, characters to the *right* (trailing) of the insertion point are removed.

On the K380, holding the Function (`fn`) key has no effect on the `delete` key. Characters to the *left* (leading) are always removed.

Why the difference is behavior? Is there a way to make get forward-delete with the K380? However, I would prefer not to install any software Logitech.

I tried this [*Firmware Update Tool*](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035037273-Firmware-Update-Tool). But it does not recognize my keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fn/keypress combinations are combined in the keyboard before being sent to the computer.

Windows uses these Fn combos in a completely different way to Mac. Testing on a Logitech K830, Fn/Backspace actually sends what the Mac reads as F13.

On the upside, the keyboard has a dedicated Del key right above the Backspace key.

I suppose you could try Ukelele or even Karabiner to remap this - I have little to no experience with either.

Comment: You mention of `Del` key above `Backspace` key confused me, as mine K380 has only a `delete`, and above that is a triangle with line under it, for ejecting CD-ROM disk (as I recall). So I dug around on the interwebs. Logitech must have released different versions or editions of the K380. I found pictures of at least three different layouts. Now Logitech.com has [this image](https://resource.logitech.com/w_695,c_limit,q_auto,f_auto,dpr_2.0/d_transparent.gif/content/dam/logitech/en/products/keyboards/multi-keyboard-k380/k380-grey-intro.png?v=1) clearly showing a `del` key above a `back` key.

Answer (score 4):

I just purchased a K380 for Mac and I can confirm it does not have a <kbd>Del</kbd> key, only <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> does not forward delete like other keyboards.

I've tried to switch keys around but Logitech Options software doesn't have the ability.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/321675)

Comment: Thank you @Alper I currently cannot comment on Basil's comment, but I wanted to share my experience with the keyboard in case anyone had questions about this functionality in 2022.

Comment: @dasbuilder - I would like to thank you for posting. It confirms that I'm not the only one facing the same thing. Helps troubleshoot by trying alternate methods that way.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this is to press:
 <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using only the Backspace key. My problem was with the Photos app. I couldn't delete a photo without the mouse. Also, you can delete a file using the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Comment: It is not clear how your answer addresses the problem in the question. The Stack Exchange web sites are not forums. Pls enter an answer only if it clearly helps with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make a rule with Karabiner as @Tetsujin mentioned as a possible solution. What I found is that it seems like no input is detected when pressing FN on the keyboard. I think it is an issue with the firmware, so hopefully, Logitech will see this post and release new firmware for the K380.

My rule for Karabiner

```
{
    "title": "My modifications",
    "rules": [
        {
            "description": "FN + backspace to be forward delete on Logitech K380 keyboard, MacOS",
            "manipulators": [
                {
                    "type": "basic",
                    "from": {
                        "simultaneous": [
                            {
                                "key_code": "fn"
                            },
                            {
                                "key_code": "delete_or_backspace"
                            }
                        ],
                        "modifiers": {
                            "optional": [
                                "any"
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "to": [
                        {
                            "key_code": "delete_forward"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this "Fn" key is not the usual "Fn" key, it is Logitech only key.